# How can I render only first paragraph using jinja

Tags: django, jinja2

I am using Django to create a website. I have a jinja variable called `content`

```
<p>paragraph1</p>
<p>paragraph2</p>
<img... />
<p>paragraph3</p>
...
```

I know I can truncate it using

```
{{ content | truncatewords_html:10 | safe }}
```

but it's not what exactly I want, I want to render the first `<p>` tag only, how can I do it with jinja?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible AFAIK. You'd need to create a custom template tag.

See: https://www.webforefront.com/django/useandcreatejinjaextensions.html